# Check whether function has run fully before, based on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which "types" out a header title as though it is being typed on the screen.

The typer only starts typing once a particular section of my site is "active" or is seen on the screen.

At present, it takes the `outputID` aka the area where this text will be typed into. There are two instances of this function being run, each with different `outputID`s - I only want the function to run *once per outputID*.

This is how the function is initially called.

```
<h2 id="typer-get-in-touch" class="typer" data-text="Get in Toche^^^^^ Touch"></h2>

if(anchorLink == 'contact'){
    var outputID = $("#typer-get-in-touch");
    textTyping(outputID);
}else if(anchorLink == 'expertise'){
    var outputID = $("#typer-expertise");
    textTyping(outputID);
}
```

This is the `textTyping` function

```
function textTyping(outputID){
        $(outputID).show();
        var textString = $(outputID).data("text");
        var textArray = textString.split("");
        var texttypeing = setInterval(
            function() {
                typeOutText(outputID,textArray);
            }, 170);

        function typeOutText(outputID,textArray) {
            if (textArray[0] == "^"){
                outputID.text(function(index, text){
                    return text.replace(/(\s+)?.$/, '');
                });
                textArray.shift();
            }else {
                if (textArray.length > 0) {
                    outputID.append(textArray.shift());
                } else {
                    clearTimeout(texttypeing);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My issue at present is that the function runs multiple types, and continues to type each time the original `anchorLink` trigger is achieved. The result is that is writes the title many times e.g:

`Get In TouchGet In TouchGet In Touch`

Each time the section is navigated to, the typing starts again.

**How can I run this function only ONCE *per outputID***? So once the outputID has been used, the function can no longer run for that data?

### JSFiddle of non-working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qLez8zeq/

### JSFiddle of mplungjan's solution: https://jsfiddle.net/qLez8zeq/1/

Comment: Outer variable/debouncing/throttling won't give you 100% protection, the only way to deal with async stuff is to use promises/callbacks. Could you publish a sample?

Comment: _"There are two instances of this function being run, each with different outputIDs "_ Can include `html` for each `outputID` at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
function textTyping(outputID){ 
    $(outputID).show();
    var textString = $(outputID).data("text");
```

to

```
function textTyping(outputID){ 
   var textString = $(outputID).data("text");
   if (textString=="") return; 
   $(outputID).data("text","");
   $(outputID).show();
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fdfny2f7/)

Comment: Thanks, I've created a JSFiddle but I've also included your solution in the OP in case anyone wants to use the source code to create their own typer.

Comment: I've noticed a small bug with this. If you look at my JSFiddle for your solution, if you double click (aka run the function twice quickly) then it will type TWICE and end up with a jumbled phrase. I think I need to stop the function from running a second time as soon as it starts typing.

Comment: Excellent thanks. How can I trigger after the whole text is "complete" and typed e.g for extra animations?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Since you are copying what you need into textarray, the data-text is no longer needed. If you have more stuff, do the same with that or create a JavScript Notation and JSON.parse it: `data-text='{ "text":"Get in Toche^^^^^ Touch","image":"typing.gif"}'>`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that when the typing is complete I am trying to trigger another function/animation to occur. The setinterval runs the function multiple times, so I'm trying to hook into the last time it runs so that I can confirm the typing animation is fully complete.

Comment: `} else {
                    clearTimeout(texttypeing); otherFunction();
                }`

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to bind the event handler for each ID and then unbind it after it's been triggered the first time. Since you're already using jQuery, you can use the ["one" method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to do exactly this for each outputID:

```
$( "#typer-get-in-touch" ).one( "click", function() {
   textTyping(outputID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could store your processed outputIds into an array and then check if the given outputId is present in the array before starting?

Define your array, check for the existence, if not found, do code example:

```
var processedIds = [];

function textTyping(outputID) {
    var foundItem = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < processedIds.length; i++)
    {  
       if (processedIds[i] == outputID) {
         foundItem = true;
         break;
       }
    }

    if (!foundItem) {
       //the rest of your code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some check at the beginning of your function:

```
var called = {};

function textTyping(outputID) {
    if (called[outputID]) {
        return;
    }
    called[outputID] = true;
    // your code
}
```